# Load/Fetch initial list if selected item not found

Tags: angular, rxjs, ngrx, ngrx-effects

I'm kinda new to the ngrx/rxjs world and trying to figure out how to set up my effects in my Angular app in a proper way, using ngrx.

I have two working scenarios:

- Load/Fetch list – load list from api and store to state
- Select item – get item by id from previously loaded list

**Now, the effect logic I'm looking for is:**

> If selected item is not found in state param `entities: Item[]` – AND the state param `initialLoaded===false` – then run action LIST_LOAD before trying to select by id (again).

Or simply:

> If `initialLoaded===false`, then run LIST_LOAD before doing the usual  ITEM_SELECT.

.

.

My current code for the ITEM_SELECT effect, to get us started:

```js
@Effect() selectItemEffect: Observable<Action> = this.actions$
        .ofType(MyActions.ActionTypes.ITEM_SELECT)
        .withLatestFrom(this.store$)
        .map(([action, state]) => {

            const id = (<MyActions.ItemSelectAction>action).id;
            const selectedItem = state.myItems.entities.find(x => x.id === id);

            if(selectedItem){
                return new MyActions.SelectSuccessAction(selectedItem);

            } else {
                /* 
                if(!state.myItems.initialLoaded) {
                     // run MyActions.ListLoadAction()?
                     // should be a nicer rxjs method for these scenarios?
                }
                */
                return new MyActions.ItemSelectFailureAction(new Error('Item not found'));

            }
        })
```

Answer (score 2):

Set up an easier solution. Set up a 3 different actions, 2 loading the item list and another one returning a selected item.

If the item is not found, simply trigger another action that calls a service that performs an api call to fetch that item by its id.

But, anyways, I feel like you are handling it in a tricky way, you can separate action handling in this way:

- Effect: only `LOAD_ITEMS`
- Reducer: `LOAD_SUCCESS`, `SELECT`

Let's suppse you have a `Item` class that models one of your items and that your `item.id` is a `string`, you should have an action like:

```
import { Action } from '@ngrx/store';

/** App Models **/
import { Item } from '../models/item.model';

export const LOAD = '[Item] Load';
export const LOAD_SUCCESS = '[Item] Load Success';
export const SELECT = '[Item] Select';

export class LoadAction implements Action {
  readonly type = LOAD;
  constructor() { }
}

export class LoadActionSuccess implements Action {
  readonly type = LOAD_SUCCESS;
  constructor(public payload: Item[]) { }
}

export class SelectAction implements Action {
  readonly type = SELECT;
  constructor(public payload: string) {}
}

export type All
  = LoadAction
  | LoadActionSuccess
  | SelectAction;
```

Then, you need an effect to perform an api call using a service to return the first list of items:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Actions, Effect } from '@ngrx/effects';

/** rxjs **/
import {map} from 'rxjs/operators/map';
import {mergeMap} from 'rxjs/operators/mergeMap';
import {catchError} from 'rxjs/operators/catchError';

/** ngrx **/
import * as itemsActions from '../actions/items.actions';
/** App Services **/
import { ItemService } from '../services/item.service';
/** App Model **/
import {Item} from '../models/content.model';

@Injectable()
export class ItemsEffects {

  @Effect() load$ = this.actions$
    .ofType(itemsActions.LOAD)
      .pipe(
        mergeMap(() => {
          return this.itemsService.getItemsFromApi()
            .pipe(
              map((items: Item[]) => {
                return new itemsActions.LoadActionSuccess(items);
              }),
              catchError((error: Error) => {
                // handle error here
              })
            );
        })
    )
  ;

  constructor(private itemsService: ItemsService, private actions$: Actions) { }
}
```

And then you'll need to have a reducer to handle both `Success` and `Select`:

```
/** ngrx **/
import {createFeatureSelector} from '@ngrx/store';
import {createSelector} from '@ngrx/store';

/** App Models **/
import { Item } from '../models/item.model';

/** ngrx **/
import * as itemsActions from '../actions/items.actions';

export type Action = itemsActions.All;

export interface ItemsState {
  items: Item[];
  selectedItem: Item;
}

export const initialState: ContentsState = {
  items: [],
  selectedItem: new Item()
};

export const selectItems = createFeatureSelector<ItemsState>('items');
export const getItems    = createSelector(selectItems, (state: ItemsState) => {
  return state.items;
});
export const getItemById = createSelector(selectItems, (state: ItemsState) => {
  return state.selectedItem;
});

export function itemsReducer(state: ItemsState = initialState, action: Action): ItemsState {
  switch (action.type) {
    case itemsActions.LOAD_SUCCESS:
      const loadedItems = action.payload.map(item => new Item(item));
      return {
               ...state,
               items: loadedItems,
               selectedItem: state.selectedItem
      };
    case itemsActions.SELECT:
      // Find one item containing id equals to the one we passed
      const filteredItem = state.items.filter((item) => {
          return item.id === action.payload
      })[0];
      return {
               ...state,
               items: state.items,
               selectedItem: filteredItem
      };
    default: {
      return state;
    }
  }
}
```

Of course, on your component you should get new values with something like:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Store } from '@ngrx/store';

/** rxjs **/
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { Subject } from 'rxjs/Subject';

/** ngrx **/
import {AppState} from '../../shared/app-state.interface';
import * as itemsActions from './actions/items.actions';
import {getItemById, getItems} from './reducers/items.reducer';

/** App Models **/
import { Item } from './models/item.model';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-items',
  templateUrl: './items.component.html'
})

export class ItemsComponent implements OnInit {

    items$: Observable<Array<Item>>;
    selectedItems$: Observable<Item>;
    selectItemById$ = new Subject<string>();

    constructor(private store: Store<AppState>) {
        this.items$ = this.store.select(getItems);
        this.selectedItems$ = this.store.select(getItemById);
        this.selectItemById$
            .switchMap(id => this.store.dispatch(new itemsActions.SelectAction(id)));
    }

    ngOnInit() {
         this.store.dispatch(new itemsActions.LoadAction());
    }

}
```

And the selection gets done in your template with something like:

```
<... (input)="selectItemById$.next(id)"/>
```

`AppState` is just an interface like:

```
import {ItemsState} from './items/reducers/items.reducers';

export interface AppState {
  items: ItemsState;
}
```

Or in any other way you wish.

Comment: Thank you for your input, @AndreaM16. 

Your code is similar to what I have. But this force me to always dispatch LOAD_ITEM before SELECT in my component, right? 

What I was looking for is to simplify the steps in the component, so when ONLY dispatching SELECT, it will automatically run LOAD_ITEMS if not already loaded - as a fallback. 

But maybe I'm over-complicating things and should just settle to always do both LOAD_ITEMS + SELECT in component, when needed?

Comment: That's not what I meant. You simply select on already fetched items from api. You can delegate such thing to a service that returns you the selected item or an error if it is not found. Then, on the reducer, you catch the error, if you get it you call another action that using an effect performs an api call like `GET item?id=testid` that returns you only the missing one, then, you stick it into your `state.selectedItem` and add it to your `state.items`. Also take a look at ngrx entities that help you doing CRUD operations in this way.

Comment: To people visiting this post pay attention to the technique @AndreaM16 is refering to (I'm adding emphasis on it because its easy to miss)! The approach he recommends is indeed an elusively-obvious gem when it comes to cache-checking: " If the item is not found, simply trigger another action that calls a service that performs an api call to fetch that item by its id. " So simple, so elegant and so concise!